# Divisors of $s(2s+1)$ and the primes $s^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

I need help proving that $s^2+1$ is prime in the following claim.

> ***claim:***  If $s$ is any positive integer I write $f_s =s(2s+1)$. I will need the divisor counting function $\tau$. Suppose that  $3s+1$
>   is prime and $\tau(f_s)=8$ then: $2^{-1}s$, $2s+1$ and $s^2+1$ are prime.

Let $q=2^{-1}s$ then I can write out the eight divisors as:

\begin{align}
 1,2,q,s,2s+1,q^{-1}s(2s+1),2^{-1}s(2s+1),s(2s+1) \end{align}

I can write $f_s =2q(2s+1)$. Surely $(2,2s+1)=1$ and$(2,q)=1$ then $\tau(2q(2s+1))=\tau(2)\tau(q(2s+1))=2\tau(q(2s+1))=8$. Consequently $\tau(q(2s+1))=4$. If $(q,(2s+1))>1$ then $f_s>8$ a contradiction. In particular $\tau(q(2s+1))=\tau(q)\tau(2s+1)=4$. Both $q$ and $2s+1$ are greater than $1$ so I have that $\tau(q)$ and $\tau(2s+1)$ are both equal to $2$ and so $q$ and $2s+1$ are prime. Note that $4q+1=2s+1$ and $6q+1=3s+1$.  Currently I cannot get to the primality of $s^2+1$. Check out the table below:
\begin{array}{| l | l | l | l |l|}
\hline
s & f_{s} & q & 2s+1& 3s+1 & s^2+1\\ \hline
6 & 78 &  3 & 13 & 19 & 37\\ 
14 & 406 &  7 & 29 & 43 & 197\\ 
26 & 1378 &  13 & 53 & 79 & 677\\ 
74 & 11026 & 37 & 149 & 223 & 5477\\ 
146 & 42778 & 73 & 293 & 439 & 21317\\ 
    \hline
    \end{array}

We can compare $q$ to [A186721](https://oeis.org/A186721) and $2s+1$ to [A090866](https://oeis.org/A090866).

***Update***: The above claim is false by computational counter example see the comment below and the Sage Program. We do have the following result though.

> ***claim:***  If $s$ is any positive integer I write $f_s =s(2s+1)$. I will  need the divisor counting function $\tau$. Suppose that  $3s+1$
>   is prime and $\tau(f_s)=8$ then: $2^{-1}s$ and $2s+1$ are prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setting, we have

**1. $q$ is prime**

**2. $4q+1$ is prime**

**3. $6q+1$ is prime**

Your questions is whether $4q^2 +1$ is prime.

Running the following program in SAGE, we find that $4q^2+1$ is not prime for $q=277$.

```
for p in primes(100000):
    if is_prime(4*p+1)==1:
        if is_prime(6*p+1)==1:
            if is_prime(4*p^2+1)==0:
                print p;
```

This gives the following result:

```
277
373
577
727
853
1033
1423
1453
1777
1987
2293
2677
2767
3037
3163
3457
...
```

It looks like there would be infinitely many such primes, but this will be of difficulty as at least [Sophie Germain Primes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime).